# DensityPlot Equation in function of variable

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

How can I plot this equation

`1/2 * Sqrt[1 + 4 Exp[-2 k t] (Exp[k t] + Cosh[2 g t]) Sinh[g t]^2 - Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Exp[-4 k t] (-1 + Exp[k t] + Cosh[2 g t])^2 Sinh[2 g t]^2]] == 0.5`

in function of the variable t, with {k, 0, 3} and {g, 0, 5}, using a DensityPlot.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you want;  could you edit the question to be clearer?  The only thing I can think of that might help is `Manipulate`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: So you want to solve your equation for t and plot it, for the various values of k and g, correct?

Comment: Yes, I need to solve this equation for t and plot for the values of k and g. Can be using a Manipulate or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to create a function that solves for `t`. This works...note that I am treating it as a minimization of a squared term...

```
minT[k_, g_] :=  t /. (Minimize[(1/2*
     Sqrt[1 + 4 Exp[-2 k t] (Exp[k t] + Cosh[2 g t]) Sinh[g t]^2 -
        Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
         Exp[-4 k t] (-1 + Exp[k t] + Cosh[2 g t])^2 Sinh[
            2 g t]^2]] - 0.5)^2, t] // Last // Last)

minT[2,2]

(*  -0.181835 *)
```

Not sure it is a proper function, in that `t` may not be single valued. Then you just run this within `DensityPlot`. Slow process, so I'll create a `Table` and `ListDensityPlot` that.

```
 Table[minT[k, g], {k, 0, 3, .1}, {g, 0, 5,.1}] // ListDensityPlot
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

notice the expression only has effectively two unknowns, being the quantities `k t` and `g t`

```
ktf[gt_] := 
 Module[{kt}, 
  kt /. NSolve[
     1/2*Sqrt[
        1 + 4 Exp[-2 kt] (Exp[kt] + Cosh[2 gt]) Sinh[gt]^2 - 
         Sqrt[2] Sqrt[
           Exp[-4 kt] (-1 + Exp[kt] + Cosh[2 gt])^2 Sinh[2 gt]^2]] == 
      1/2, kt, Reals][[1]]]
Plot[ ktf[gt] , {gt, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

given that solution we can readily generate contour lines of constant `t`:

```
ktofgt = FunctionInterpolation[ktf[gt], {gt, 0, 1}]
Show[Table[
  ParametricPlot[{gt/t, ktofgt[gt]/t}, {gt, 0, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> All], {t, .1, 5, .1}], PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}]
```

[image]

for a density plot use the same approach to generate a data table.
(Note your system admits +/- t solutions, this gives only the t>0 solution.)

```
d = Select[ 
   Select[Flatten[
     Table[{gt/10^logt, ktofgt[gt]/10^logt, 10^logt}, {gt, 0, 
       1, .001}, {logt, -2, 2, .01}], 1], VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &] , 
   0 < #[[1]] < 5 && 0 < #[[2]] < 5 && #[[3]] < 10 &];

     ListDensityPlot[d]
```

[image]

note the blank around (0,0) is because t is going to infinity. the blank around 0,5 is because there is no solution.   A Plot3D is a better way to visualize this.

```
  ListPlot3D[d, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

repeating the exercise to grab the negative t solution:

[image]

Comment: This a good solution too, but I need a densityplot for these variables (g and k). Thanks for your help

Comment: see edit.          15char